# C# - Variável tipo long

Tags: c#

No programa abaixo, eu peço pra Calcular a distância, em km, percorrida pela luz em um intervalo de tempo no formato "HH:MM:SS".
Quando eu entro com o valor 02:30:00 ao invés de dar 2700000000 o programa me retorna o valor -1594967296.
O que há de errado no meu código?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Calcular a distância, em km, percorrida pela luz em um intervalo de tempo no formato "HH:MM:SS".
        int hora, minutos, segundos;
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o intervalo de tempo no formato \"HH:MM:SS\":");
        string tempo = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] vetor = tempo.Split(':');
        hora = int.Parse(vetor[0]);
        minutos = int.Parse(vetor[1]);
        segundos = int.Parse(vetor[2]);
        long distancia = (((hora * 60 * 60) + (minutos * 60) + (segundos)) * 300000);
        Console.WriteLine("A luz percorreu {0} km nesse intervalo.", distancia);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: olá já fez debug no código? tentou ver se os valores das variáveis hora, minuto e segundo estão ok e simular o cálculo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema aqui é que o as variáveis todas são do tipo `int`, então todo o cálculo é feito com esse tipo antes de atribuir à variável

Na documentação: [Numeric Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) temos:

> int   -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

O resultado do cálculo será 2574000000, o que excede o valor positivo do tipo `int`, que no máximo é 2147483647.
Para corrigir isso, antes de atribuir o valor à variável deve fazer um *cast*, ou conversão, para que o cálculo seja todo atribuido corretamente, assim:

`long distancia = (long)((hora * 60 * 60) + (minutos * 60) + segundos) * 300000`;

ou ainda melhor, já que há um cast: `var distancia = (long)((hora * 60 * 60) + (minutos * 60) + segundos) * 300000`;

Pode ver aqui o código funcionando: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gTTrFg

**NOTA**: não relacionado à pergunta mas...
`hora = int.Parse(vetor[0]);` - aqui já está assumindo que, foi digitado um valor correto no formato "hh:mm:ss", se o valor estiver incorreto, pode dar erro nessa linha ou nas seguntes (se digitar por exemplo nada, ou 01:22 ou ainda "xpto"). É importante validar isso antes.

Pode por exemplo tentar converter o valor para uma data e ver o resultado, assim:

```
var valido = DateTime.TryParseExact(tempo, 
                                "HH:mm:ss",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                DateTimeStyles.None,
                                out var result);
        
if (!valido)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Periodo inválido");
    return;
}
```

O método `TryParseExact` returna um bool, ou seja, `true` se conseguiu converter e `false` se não, uma forma simples de validar a entrada antes de tentar fazer o `split`